# Output volume control isn't working

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

The sound volume in the menu bar and the volume button on my keyboard doesn't change the output volume when I connect headphones or external speakers on my MBP.
When I go to System Preferences -> Sound the Output volume bar does work.
Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is that your desktop volume control is actually connected to the device whose volume you're trying to control. In Lion, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+clicking the volume icon allows you to switch its function (and that of the keyboard shortcuts) between all connected output and input devices, plus any software devices such as *Soundflower* or *Boom* that might be running. I do find that it occasionally gets confused when plugging/unplugging devices, although not usually with simple headphones/speakers.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me intermittently, but have never been able to identify a source for the problem. Even though it seems inconvenient, the thing that fixes it every time: restart. Give it a go.